# SQL Query calculate stock in hand in view table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table StockIn and StockOut, I want to create a view table to show stock in hand. I am able to ahieve it, but if the particular product is entered in StockIn table and is not been sold out and doesn't have its entry in StockOut table then in my view table the stock in hand for this particular product shows null. Please can anyone fix this.

Below is my query:

```
SELECT
  si.Id,
  si.AId,
  si.AssetsName,
  si.PTypeId,
  si.ProductType, 
  si.Rate,
  si.Qty,  

 SUM(so.QtyOut) AS QtyOut,  
 COALESCE(si.Qty, 0) - SUM(so.QtyOut) AS StockInHand
FROM dbo.StockIn si 
LEFT JOIN dbo.StockOut so ON so.Id = si.Id
GROUP BY 
  si.Id,
  si.AId,
  si.AssetsName,
  si.PTypeId,
  si.ProductType, 
  si.Rate,
  si.Qty
  ;
GO
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please check following article http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/stock-aging-using-sqlscript-on-sap-hana-database.aspx There is a section for Net Quantity. I hope it helps

Comment: have you tried ISNULL(SUM(so.QtyOut),0) -- ISNULL(COALESCE(si.Qty, 0) - SUM(so.QtyOut), 0) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle NULL cases as follows

```
 isnull(SUM(so.QtyOut),0) AS QtyOut,  
 COALESCE(si.Qty, 0) - isnull(SUM(so.QtyOut),0) AS StockInHand
```

In an arithmetic operation if one side is NULL then result turns into NULL

So, set these NULL values to ZERO as above

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `COALESCE` on the quantity from the table on the *right* side of the left join:

```
SELECT
    si.Id,
    si.AId,
    si.AssetsName,
    si.PTypeId,
    si.ProductType, 
    si.Rate,
    si.Qty,  
    COALESCE(SUM(so.QtyOut), 0) AS QtyOut,
    si.Qty - COALESCE(SUM(so.QtyOut), 0) AS StockInHand
FROM dbo.StockIn si 
LEFT JOIN dbo.StockOut so
    ON so.Id = si.Id
GROUP BY
    si.Id,
    si.AId,
    si.AssetsName,
    si.PTypeId,
    si.ProductType, 
    si.Rate,
    si.Qty;
```

The issue here is that a given `StockIn` entry might not match to anything in the `StockOut` table during the join.  In this case, logically you want that `NULL` missing out quantity to become zero.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen, its working but how about those NULL value. Can these NULL value be replaced by default 0, if so can you please show that too.

Comment: I don't know what "those NULL value" means here.  Based on your current output table, my answer should have resolved all the `NULL` values, at least from what I can see.

Comment: @Turing . . . `COALESCE(SUM(so.QtyOut)) AS QtyOut,`.